# Basic GSM phone with a monochrome display

Tags: mobile-phone

I'm looking to replace my Nokia 1280 with a phone that supports U.S. bands as well as European ones.

- An STN LCD monochrome display (better readability in direct sunlight)
- A sufficiently large battery. It depends on the power consumption of the phone, though: my N1280 phone has a 800mAh battery and I'm perfectly happy with the standby time it provides (~10-12 days).
- Quad-band: the reason I'm seeking to upgrade is that N1280 does not support American GSM bands.
- That's basically it; I only need the phone to be able to send/receive SMS and make phone calls. The SMS memory size doesn't matter.

Any advice? Thank you!

Comment: Hi welcome to Hardware Recs! It would help us more if you're able to post a desired price range as well as some ball park numbers for SMS cap and battery life (preferably mAh if you know what that means, but battery life in hours is fine as well).

Comment: What about e-ink instead of STN? You'll get much better battery life and readability in direct sunlight, and it should be fine for SMS/calls only.

Comment: I think it may work for me. Can you recommend an e-ink screen phone model?